# Play a sound after time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have a script that plays a sound after some time but it only plays the sound the second time.
Here is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class soundPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{

    float timer;
    [SerializeField] private AudioSource prrr;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() 
    {
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
    
        if (timer >= 3f)
        {
            gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipX = true;   
            prrr.Play();
        }
        if (timer >= 6f)
        {
            prrr.Play();
            gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipX = false;
            timer = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

As I said, I expect the sound to play 2 times.

Comment: Have you tried to print the timer value and see what is happening? Maybe the sound is played only once or the two sound are mixed together?

Comment: how can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

the `timer` **remains** `>= 3f` while you keep increasing it!

It will play the sounds **every frame** while `timer` is between `3` and `6`, so according to [`AudioSource.Play`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.Play.html) it is always **re-started** and you probably hear almost nothing.

---

I would suggest a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html):

```
public class soundPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private AudioSource prrr;

    IEnumerator Start()
    {
        var spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

        yield return new WaitforSeconds(3f);

        spriteRenderer.flipX = true;   
        prrr.Play();

        yield return new WaitforSeconds(3f);

        prrr.Play();
        spriteRenderer.flipX = false;
    }
}
```

and if your intend is to keep this repeating forever you simply make it a loop

```
public class soundPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private AudioSource prrr;
    
    IEnumerator Start()
    {
        var spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

        while(true)
        {
            yield return new WaitforSeconds(3f);

            spriteRenderer.flipX = !spriteRenderer.flipX;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Of course you can do the same without a Coroutine but imho this looks more complex

```
public class soundPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private AudioSource prrr;

    SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;
    float timer;   
    int flipCount;     

    void Start()
    {
        spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        timer += Time.deltaTime;

        if(timer >= 3f) 
        {
            spriteRenderer.flipX = !spriteRenderer.flipX;
            prrr.Play();
            timer -= 3f;

            // simply count how often you reached the flip time
            flipCount++;

            // an stop after 2
            if(flipCount >= 2)
            {
                // disable so Update isn't called anymore
                enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

or accordingly for looping forever

```
public class soundPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private AudioSource prrr;

    SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;
    float timer;        

    void Start()
    {
        spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        timer += Time.deltaTime;

        if(timer >= 3f) 
        {
            spriteRenderer.flipX = !spriteRenderer.flipX;
            prrr.Play();
            timer -= 3f;
        }
    }
}
```